# Problems on xpath in nodejs scrapejs

Tags: node.js, xpath

```
    sp = require('scrapejs').init({
            cc:100,
            delay:1*1000
    });

    sp.load('http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Elite')
    .then(function($){
            var counter = 0
            //$.q('//*[@id="tblproxy"]/tbody/tr[3]').forEach(function(node){
            $.q('//tbody/tr').forEach(function(node){
            //$.q("/html/body/div[1]/div[0]/table/tbody/tr").forEach(function(node){
                    console.log(counter)
                    var res = {
                            prx: node.textContent
                    }
                    console.log(res)
                    counter+=1
            })
            console.log(counter)
    })
    .fail(function(err){
            console.log("srsly")
    })
```

I am trying to scrape some proxy server's information from the webpage, but the xpath extracted by the google inspection tools doesn't work, I want to know how to fix it.

so the xpath I extracted is //*[@id="tblproxy"]/tbody/tr, not sure why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with xpath. The problem is that the HTML you see in your browser is *not* the HTML that `scrapejs` sees. The table is generated with JavaScript.

If you download the "raw" site, for example with `curl` or `wget`, you will see each table row consisting of a bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    gp.insertPrx({"PROXY_CITY":"","PROXY_COUNTRY":"Singapore","PROXY_IP":"119.81.199.86","PROXY_LAST_UPDATE":"1 29","PROXY_PORT":"50","PROXY_REFS":null,"PROXY_STATE":"","PROXY_STATUS":"OK","PROXY_TIME":"22","PROXY_TYPE":"Elite","PROXY_UID":null,"PROXY_UPTIMELD":"21/13"});
</script>
```

Comment: Any suggestions how to scrap the parameters being passed to gp.insertPrx,  that's the info I think we need to scrape